# How to create a stream wrapping stream that can transform a stream

Tags: c#, stream

```
var incomingStream = ...
var outgoingStream = ...

await incomingStream.CopyToAsync(outgoingStream);
```

The above code is simple enough, and copies a incoming stream to the outgoign stream. Both streams being chunked transfers coming/going over the interet.

Now, lets say i wanted to Transform the stream with something like `Func<Stream,Stream,Task>` how would I do that without reading all data in.

Ofcause I could just do

```
var ms = new MemoryStream();
incomingStream.CopyTo(ms);

--- do transform of streams and seek
ms.CopyTo(outgoingStream)
```

but that would read the hole thing into the ms, is there any build in stuff that allows me to read from incoming stream and write to a new stream that dont buffer everything up but instead just keep a small internal stream for buffered data and it wont read from incoming stream before data is pulled off it again.

What I am trying to do is:

```
    protected async Task XmlToJsonStream(Stream instream, Stream outStream)
    {
        XmlReaderSettings readerSettings = new XmlReaderSettings();
        readerSettings.IgnoreWhitespace = false;
        var reader = XmlReader.Create(instream, readerSettings);
        var jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(new StreamWriter(outStream));
        jsonWriter.WriteStartObject();

        while (await reader.ReadAsync())
        {
            jsonWriter.writeReader(reader);
        }
        jsonWriter.WriteEndObject();
        jsonWriter.Flush();
    }
    protected async Task XmlFilterStream(Stream instream, Stream outStream)
    {
        XmlReaderSettings readerSettings = new XmlReaderSettings();
        readerSettings.IgnoreWhitespace = false;
        var reader = XmlReader.Create(instream, readerSettings);
        var writer = XmlWriter.Create(outStream, new XmlWriterSettings { Async = true, CloseOutput = false })

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            writer.writeReader(reader);
        }


    }
```

but i dont know how to hook it up.

```
var incomingStream = ...
var outgoingStream = ...
var temp=...  
XmlFilterStream(incomingStream,temp);
XmlToJsonStream(temp,outgoingstream);
```

because if I use a MemoryStream as temp, would it not just at the end have it all stored in the stream. Looking for at stream that throws away the data again when it has been read.

All of the above is just example code, missing some disposes and seeks ofcause, but I hope I managed to illustrate what i am going for. To be able to based on settings to plug and play between just copying stream, doing xml filtering and optional transform it to json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Streams are sequences of *bytes*, so a stream transformation would be something like `Func<ArraySegment<byte>, ArraySegment<byte>>`. You can then apply it in a streaming way:

```
async Task TransformAsync(this Stream source, Func<ArraySegment<byte>, ArraySegment<byte>> transform, Stream destination, int bufferSize = 1024)
{
  var buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
  while (true)
  {
    var bytesRead = await source.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
    if (bytesRead == 0)
      return;
    var bytesToWrite = transform(new ArraySegment(buffer, 0, bytesRead));
    if (bytesToWrite.Count != 0)
      await destination.WriteAsync(bytesToWrite.Buffer, bytesToWrite.Offset, bytesToWrite.Count);
  }
}
```

It's a bit more complicated than that, but that's the general idea. It needs some logic to ensure `WriteAsync` writes all the bytes; and there's also usually a "flush" method that is required in addition to the `transform` method, which is called when the source stream finishes, so the transform algorithm has a last chance to return its final data to write to the output stream.

If you want streams of *other* things, like XML or JSON types, then you're probably better off going with [Reactive Extensions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx).

Comment: I see that this way is more clean, but using the streams as in my example one would be able to use the XmlReader/Writer and JsonReader/Writers to do transforms. I will think alittle more about the design.

Comment: @PoulK.Sørensen Did you ever figure out anything? I am in similar situation.  Trying to use SqlClient Streaming which just takes a 'stream' as a parameter, but I want to compress the original stream as it goes into database.  So essentially I want to wrap original stream (i.e. a `FileStream`) with a `GZipStream` so that every time SqlClient Streaming presumably initiates a `ReadAsync` that my wrapper stream would first read data from underlying stream, compress the data then return the compressed bytes to SqlClient Streaming.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question fully, but I think you're asking how you would operate on an input stream without loading it entirely into memory first.

In this case, you wouldn't want do do something like this:

```
var ms = new MemoryStream();
incomingStream.CopyTo(ms);
```

This *does* load the entire input stream `incomingStream` into memory -- into `ms`.

From what I can see, your `XmlFilterStream` method seems to be redundant, i.e. `XmlToJsonStream` does everything that `XmlFilterStream` does anyway.

Why not just have:

```
protected async Task XmlToJsonStream(Stream instream, Stream outStream)
{
    XmlReaderSettings readerSettings = new XmlReaderSettings();
    readerSettings.IgnoreWhitespace = false;
    var reader = XmlReader.Create(instream, readerSettings);
    var jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(new StreamWriter(outStream));
    jsonWriter.WriteStartObject();

    while (await reader.ReadAsync())
    {
        jsonWriter.writeReader(reader);
    }
    jsonWriter.WriteEndObject();
    jsonWriter.Flush();
}
```

And call it like this:

```
var incomingStream = ...
var outgoingStream = ...
XmlToJsonStream(incomingStream ,outgoingstream);
```

If the answer is that you have omitted some important details in `XmlFilterStream` then, without seeing those details, I would recommend that you just integrate those into the one `XmlToJsonStream` function.

Comment: Sorry for leaving out to much then.  The XmlFilterStream would do more than just read/write, it would read xml, (if (Include(reader) { writer(reader))  . But I get your point